# Ignore spring dependency injection : XML

Tags: java, xml, spring

```
Project X
---------
public class A {}

Public class B{
    @Autowire
    private A a;

    @Autowire
    private D d;
}


Project Y
---------
Public class C{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/application-Context.xml");
        B b = context.getBean("b", B.class);
    }
}

application-Context.xml
<bean id="a" class="A" />
<bean id="b" class="B" />
```

Question:
I have setup like above, where I have binary of Project X, and currently I am  working on Project Y. I want to create Class B object without creating D in Project Y. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: you can not change the class B?you have only binary?

Comment: Yeah, without touching Project X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this field in autowired annotation.

```
@Autowired(required=false)
private D d;
```

In case you don't have access to project X, there is you have to do some kind of hack.

On your project create Class that marked as service and extend D class so in that case spring will inject your class.

```
@Component
@Primary
public class MockD extends D {

}
```

In that case @Primary will say to spring to take this with priority instead of other implementation. So your class will be injected to class B

Comment: Problem is I dont have access to Project X

Comment: Edit my comment, This is a hack but you don't have any other choice if you can't access project x

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection is never mandatory. It is upto the programmer wheather s/he wants to inject the bean or not.

So here in B's definition, you can simply inject just bean A as given below:

```
application-Context.xml
<bean id="a" class="A" />
<bean id="b" class="B" >
    <property name="a" ref="a" />
</bean>
```

Only if class B extends `InitializingBean` and overrides `afterPropertiesSet` method and checks if D is injected, then only it may cause issue, or else you would be good with above injection. No need to create and inject bean D as such.

Comment: in my application-context.xml file I have
<context:annotation-config/>

it throws:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [x.y.z.D] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--<context:annotation-config/>-->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
<property name="requiredParameterValue" value="false" />
```

instead of adding annotation-config, have to add above one